# SSRS Date value is not valid

Tags: reporting-services

A few weeks ago the guys who handle our servers upgraded from MSSQL2008 R2 to MSSQL2012 ServicePack 2
Now all the reports where we pass a date parameter from our application give us an error.

The date in the database is in the following format: "DD-MM-YYYY 00:00:00:0000"
So we changed the value we are passing from our application to fit this format, but the date is still invalid.

We don't debug on the server, so we installed all relevant versions locally and it worked fine.

Anybody else had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have had that problem with a update from SQL2012 to SQL2014. But that was caused by the fact that SQL 2014 has more datefields. This is not relevant for you.

In your case though,  I would change all the fields to this format:
"**YYYY-MM-DD** 00:00:00:0000". You can reformat it in the report if you want it to be shown like "**DD-MM-YYYY** 00:00:00:0000"

I suspect it has something to do with regional settings somewehere. When using YYYY-MM-DD  instead of DD-MM-YYYY you avoid al that sh*t.
I always use **YYYY-MM-DD** to avoid confusing.